Properties of the Bochner function space $L^{p \times q}([0,1] \times X)$
The function space $L^{p \times q}([0,1] \times X)$ is a variant of $L^p$-space which is a collection of functions whose norm $$\|f \|_{p \times q} := \| \| f(t, x) \|_{L^q(x:X)} \|_{L^p(t:[0,1])}$$ is finite.
It could be easily shown that $f(t_0, x)$ is in $L^q(X)$ for almost every $t_0 \in [0,1]$, but could we do more?
Mainly, I will assume that $X$ is a closed manifold with a measure induced by the Riemannian metric. Then, I would like to ask:

Could we embed this space into another simpler space $L^r([0,1] \times X)$?

What about the closure of $C^\infty([0,1 ] \times X)$ in the space?


If there is some reference about this, I'm happy about that.

This space is the $L^p$ space $L^p([0, 1]; L^q(X))$. It's called a Bochner space, and is defined using the Bochner integral, which generalizes the Lebesgue integral.

If the measure of $X$ is finite, you get the embedding from 1 with $r = \min{ p, q}$.

You might want to check the following classic paper of Benedek and Panzone, DOI:10.1215/S0012-7094-61-02828-9
